# How to parse JSON from a multipart/mixed batch OData call in Java?

Tags: java, json, http, odata

I have a `Odata` batch endpoint that returns `multipart/mixed` response of the format -

```
--4F9FCF2B7A28D38A4662024D269B7C500
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Length: 6158
content-transfer-encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 5966
dataserviceversion: 2.0
sap-metadata-last-modified: Wed, 24 Apr 2019 10:33:59 GMT
cache-control: no-store, no-cache

{{some JSON}}
--4F9FCF2B7A28D38A4662024D269B7C500--
```

In the request header I have mentioned `Accept : application/json`. Despite that the response contains non-JSON component.

As a result, I cannot do that following in Java -

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(res);
```

Is there any library/method to parse this `multipart/mixed` response. I just want a `JSONObject` created out of the `JSON` part of the response

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: Yes. Crude solution - Split the response string from first occurrence of '{' using indexOf('{') and the last occurrence using - lastIndexOf('}'). And then convert it into JSONObject. Works for now. But would be happy if there exists a better solution.